# UITableView Cell Blur Read Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a simple iOS app project that i have been working on. The tableview shows entries that are fetched from a web service (rss feed) and tapping on one of them segues to the web view.

Using the following, i am checking if the items has been read, and if yes that it puts a check mark using setAccessoryType to indicate that the item has been read:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ItemFeed *entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[MyFeedStore sharedStore] markItemAsRead:entry];
    [[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

}
```

The above code is resulting in the following:

[image]

What i want is the cell to be blurred to indicate that it has been read. I am putting the following image from TechCrunch iPhone app as an example for what i want:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**  I have tried changing the text color in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but it didn't work:

```
ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];
cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Red color is just for checking right now
```

Comment: I can't see any blur, just a gray text color.

Comment: @A-Live can you check the updated question

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work, do you also select correct color at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`/`willDisplayCell` ?

Comment: @A-Live the default black color is selected inside the storyboard.

Comment: Storyboard knows nothing about your `ItemFeed` marked as read, you'll have to to change the color of label at initialized/reused cell when needed. Don't forget to set the default color as if the cell is reused it might have the color for read item. @Viral scroll the table.

Comment: Note you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and @Alexander Merchi gives you correct alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Red color is just for checking right now
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to change the textColor property of the label in your cell to a color similar to the Tech Crunch app's textColor.